# WSO2 Cannot login API-M carbon when use IS as Key Manager

Tags: wso2, multi-tenant

I setup IS as Key Manager for API-M. Then I tried to create new tenant

1. Login IS carbon console with super tenant
2. Create new tenant with domain and admin user
3. Login IS carbon console with new tenant's admin successfully
4. Try to login API-M carbon console with new tenant's admin.

Console of API-M shows: `CarbonAuthenticationUtil Failed Administrator login attempt 'newuser[3]'`

However, i can login in API Publisher with new user

What additional configuration that i  should do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't shared user store and permission DB correctly across APIM and IS. Please check user-mgt.xml in both products. If possible attache **user-mgt.xml** and **master-datasources.xml** in both products by removing sensitive information like database, LDAP passwords ...etc.